# Conversion Tool for GEE Javascript to Python Not Working. Getting Assertion Error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I am very new to the Earth Engine Python API and I am trying to convert a significant amount of GEE code to Python in order to have it better integrate with my larger project. I have been attempting to use the conversion tool all day, first in Jupyter Notebook in VScode and then in Jupyter Notebook within the browser.
Even for simple examples, in vscode Jupyter notebook just runs without end when I try to actually run the converted code. In the browser, the tool won't even produce the dialog box to enter the javascript. When I click on the tool, I get an "Assertion Error" in Anaconda Prompt.I read that iPyLeaflet may be causing the issues, so I downloaded version 16. That has not helped the situation. Does anyone have any tips?
[image: Command Prompt Screenshot]

[image: The furthest I get in Jupyter Notebook]

Comment: I know I maybe stating the obvious but wouldn't it be faster to simply convert it by hand (if the tool is broken) ? It will take you around an hour or two. Note that further down the road you code develop in Python directly using Jupyter sidecar option to avoid this translation issue and still mimic code editor behavior..